# How to get average data for current month with conditions?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display average of high, low and normal rates in my chart, but not sure how to get the average. Here is what I have tried..

```
$query = Rates::select('value')
              ->whereMonth('date',$val)
              ->where('user_id',$user_id)
              ->get();
$total = count($query);
$low = 0;
$high = 0;
$normal = 0;
if($total > 0) {
    foreach ($query as $val) {
        if($val->value < 60){
            $low++;
        } else if ($val->value > 90){
            $high++;
        } else {
            $normal++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a total and a count of each so the average is a simple formula

Comment: In addition to `$low` you probably want `$low_sum`, and repeat with the others. Then `+=` that with the value accordingly and divide by `$low` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an array of values and then run an average calculation on them after populating

```
$low = [];
$high = [];
$normal = [];
if($total > 0) {
    foreach ($query as $val) {
        if($val->value < 60) $low[]=$val->value;
        else if ($val->value > 90) $high[]=$val->value;
        else $normal[]=$val->value;
    }
}
$lowavg = count($low) > 0 ? array_sum($low)/count($low) : 0;
$highavg = count($high) > 0 ? array_sum($high)/count($high) : 0;
$normalavg = count($normal) > 0 ? array_sum($normal)/count($normal) : 0;
```

Comment: Good answer, I always forget `array_sum` exists, along with the other million `array_*` functions